# postgresql hstore key/value vs traditional SQL performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, hstore

I need to develop a key/value backend, something like this:

```
Table T1 id-PK, Key - string, Value - string
INSERT into T1('String1', 'Value1')
INSERT INTO T1('String1', 'Value2')

Table T2 id-PK2, id2->external key to id
some other data in T2, which references data in T1 (like users which have those K/V etc)
```

I heard about PostgreSQL hstore with GIN/GIST. What is better (performance-wise)? 
Doing this the traditional way with SQL joins and having separate columns(Key/Value) ? 
Does PostgreSQL hstore perform better in this case?

The format of the data should be any key=>any value. 
I also want to do text matching e.g. partially search for  (LIKE %  in SQL or using the hstore equivalent).
I plan to have around 1M-2M entries in it and probably scale at some point.

What do you recommend ? Going the SQL traditional way/PostgreSQL hstore or any other distributed key/value store with persistence?

If it helps, my server is a VPS with 1-2GB RAM, so not a pretty good hardware. I was also thinking to have a cache layer on top of this, but I think it rather complicates the problem. I just want good performance for 2M entries. Updates will be done often but searches even more often.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should ask this question on serverfault.com instead.

Comment: The postgres mailing list is good too, and then you could post the answer back here and pick up the points too ;-) Try http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/ or perhaps http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/.

Answer (score 10):

Your question is unclear because your not clear about your objective.

The key here is the index (pun intended) - if your dealing with a large amount of keys you want to be able to retrieve them with a the least lookups and without pulling up unrelated data.

Short answer is you probably don't want to use `hstore`, but lets look into more detail...

- Does each `id` have many key/value pairs (hundreds+)? Don't use `hstore`.
- Will any of your values contain large blocks of text (4kb+)? Don't use `hstore`.
- Do you want to be able to search by keys in wildcard expressions? Don't use `hstore`.
- Do you want to do complex joins/aggregation/reports? Don't use `hstore`.
- Will you update the value for a single key? Don't use `hstore`.
- Multiple keys with the same name under an `id`? Can't use `hstore`.

So what's the use of `hstore`? Well, one good scenario would be if you wanted to hold key/value pairs for an external application where you know you always want to retrive *all* key/values and will always save the data back as a block (ie, it's never edited in-place). At the same time you do want some flexibility to be able to search this data - albiet very simply - rather than storing it in say a block of XML or JSON. In this case since the number of key/value pairs are small you save on space because your compressing several tuples into one `hstore`.

Consider this as your table:

```
CREATE TABLE kv (
  id /* SOME TYPE */ PRIMARY KEY,
  key_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  key_value TEXT,
  UNIQUE(id, key_name)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the design is poorly normalized.  Try something more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  t1_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  <other data which depends on t1_id and nothing else>,
  -- possibly an hstore, but maybe better as a separate table
  t1_props hstore
);

-- if properties are done as a separate table:
CREATE TABLE t1_properties
(
  t1_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES t1,
  key_name text NOT NULL,
  key_value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (t1_id, key_name)
);
```

If the properties are small and you don't need to use them heavily in joins or with fancy selection criteria, and `hstore` may suffice. Elliot laid out some sensible things to consider in that regard.

Your reference to users suggests that this is incomplete, but you didn't really give enough information to suggest where those belong.  You might get by with an array in `t1`, or you might be better off with a separate table.